# How to edit the TextField value of React Material?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that comes with some data from a country. The data comes from a `GraphQL API` with `Apolo Client`.

By default, the data is read-only, if the user wants to change the value, should click on the edit button.

The problem is that I am not able to edit the value in `TextInput`, by default, the value value is already pre defined. I try to edit the value through `onChange()`, but it doesn't work.

Everything I type does not appear in the Input field.

Here's my code, I put in CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-water-p9p7l?file=/src/App.js

I'm using `TextField` from `react-material`.

[image]

Can someone help me to update that´s values? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few Change on your code:

In your cangeField function, you need 3 parameters the field with you want to change, the country ID owner of this field, and the new value for the field.
To change the value you need first find the country in the country list and then update the value for the field.

```
const changeField = (field, id, value) => {
  console.log(id, country);
  const newCountryInfo = [...country];
  newCountryInfo.forEach(c => {
    if (c._id === id) {
      c[field] = value;
      setCountry([...newCountryInfo]);
      return;
    }
  });
};
```

On your textInput you call the change field and pass the three parameters as expected first the name of the country property you want to change on this case "name" -> country.name, second the Country ID country._id and the last is the new value for the field

```
<TextField
  ...
  onChange={event => changeField('name', item._id, event.target.value)}
  ...
/>
```

You can note I remove the brace after the ES6 function '=>' because in you use this brace you need to return inside

```
<TextField
  ...
  onChange={event => {
    return changeField('name', item._id, event.target.value);
  }}
  ...
/>
```

in your code, you forgot to return but is cleaner to return directly

```
<TextField
  ...
  onChange={event => changeField('name', item._id, event.target.value)}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Hey Yoandry, that's work perfectly for me, thank you!!! The only diference, I had to change `value={item.name}` for `defaultValue={item.name}`.  Has some problem?

Comment: Hey, vbernal glad to help U! it is better to use the value props, 'defaultValue' as the semantic name implies should be used only for the case when the input does not has value or in the first render when there is no data, any change on the input will update the value prop this is the standard and if you use defaultValue instead of the value you could have accessibility problems, especial tools like NVDA could not read the right value to the user. I'm not saying defaultValue will not work, I'm just throwing an alert

Comment: Hey Yoandry, thank you, but if I let with `value` instead `defaultValue`, the solution you tell me doesn't work. Know you why? Thanks again!! :))

Comment: Sorry, vbernal was my fault, I just update the changeField function, because we only need to update the country array when a field is modified. another tip in the render inside the country map you use the item as key but an item is an object you'll need to update to   `<Grid key={item._id} container spacing={4}>`